# ggplot2 color gradient per group

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the sample I was able to make it work:

```
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$Sepal.Length, df$Sepal.Width), ]
hulls <- ddply(iris, "Species", find_hull)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species, 
                         color=Species, size=Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Sepal.Length vs. Sepal.Width - size Petal.Width") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16,17)) +
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.15, size=0.2) +
  scale_size(guide = "none")
```

What I would like to do now is to specify gradient for each of the groups (i.e., setosa, versicolor, and virginica), based on the Petal.Width. That is, let's say setosa group are read squares, where size of each point depends on the Petal.Width. I would like that this red color varies (from white to red), based on the petal width. If virginica are blue triangles, I would like that color of those triangles also varies with the size (petal width).

Any ideas what would be an easy way to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky -- to get the "fade to white" effect, I added a white `geom_point`, and overlaid that with another `geom_point` where `alpha` is mapped to `Petal.Width`.  So points with the largest values of `Petal.Width` will be solid colours, fading to white as `Petal.Width` decreases.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species, 
                         color=Species, size=Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "white") +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  ggtitle("Sepal.Length vs. Sepal.Width - size Petal.Width") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16,17)) +
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.15, size=0.2) +
  scale_size(guide = "none") +
  scale_alpha_continuous(guide = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How would I proceed it I want to specify specific colors for each of the groups (species manually), say "orange"/ "yellow"/ "black"?